# How to stretch bootstrap5 text area in tabs

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, bootstrap-5

I would like to place a text area within the tab and stretch it horizontally and vertically within the card body.

However, using `d-flex` and `align-self-stretch` does not seem to work on the tab content `div`.

Here is what I have tried. I used bootstrap5 to place tabs with text areas inside cards.

- I added a `d-flex flex-column` class to the `card-body`.
- I added `d-flex align-self-stretch` to the tab content `<div class="tab-content">`
- I have set `display: flex` from css, since there seems to be no `flex` in the `div` attribute.

However, the tab content does not fill the extra space in the card.
Is there any solution to this problem?
Thank you.

Here is a simple code that reproduces the problem.
https://codepen.io/sankai0044/pen/abEXaoJ

Here is the code.

```css
.card{
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
}

.tab-content{
  display: flex;
}

.tab-pane{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.form-group{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#MyTextarea{
  resize: none;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.slim.js" integrity="sha256-HwWONEZrpuoh951cQD1ov2HUK5zA5DwJ1DNUXaM6FsY=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
      Header
    </div>
    <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
        <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
          <button
            class="nav-link active"
            id="home-tab"
            data-bs-toggle="tab"
            data-bs-target="#home"
            type="button"
            role="tab"
            aria-controls="home"
            aria-selected="true"
          >
            Home
          </button>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
          <button
            class="nav-link"
            id="profile-tab"
            data-bs-toggle="tab"
            data-bs-target="#profile"
            type="button"
            role="tab"
            aria-controls="profile"
            aria-selected="false"
          >
            Profile
          </button>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
          <button
            class="nav-link"
            id="contact-tab"
            data-bs-toggle="tab"
            data-bs-target="#contact"
            type="button"
            role="tab"
            aria-controls="contact"
            aria-selected="false"
          >
            Contact
          </button>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="tab-content d-flex align-self-stretch" id="myTabContent">
        <div
          class="tab-pane fade show active"
          id="home"
          role="tabpanel"
          aria-labelledby="home-tab"
        >
          <div class="form-group">
            <textarea class="form-control" id="MyTextarea" disabled>This is some placeholder content the Home tab's associated content. Clicking another tab will toggle the visibility of this one for the next. The tab JavaScript swaps classes to control the content visibility and styling. You can use it with tabs, pills, and any other .nav-powered navigation.This is some placeholder content the Home tab's associated content. Clicking another tab will toggle the visibility of this one for the next. The tab JavaScript swaps classes to control the content visibility and styling. You can use it with tabs, pills, and any other .nav-powered navigation.</textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div
          class="tab-pane fade"
          id="profile"
          role="tabpanel"
          aria-labelledby="profile-tab"
        >
          Profile Content
        </div>
        <div
          class="tab-pane fade"
          id="contact"
          role="tabpanel"
          aria-labelledby="contact-tab"
        >
          Contact Content
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer">
      Footer
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `.align-self-stretch` class. You are running into problems with the original Bootstrap CSS for `.card`. To fix that you have to add the BS class `.flex-grow-1` to your `tab-content` div.

Moreover, you have to make sure that your `#myTextarea` is set to `height: 100%`.

I hope this creates the effect you were looking for.

```css
.card{
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
}

.tab-content{
  display: flex;
}

.tab-pane{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.form-group{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#MyTextarea{
  resize: none;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.slim.js" integrity="sha256-HwWONEZrpuoh951cQD1ov2HUK5zA5DwJ1DNUXaM6FsY=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
      Header
    </div>
    <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
        <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
          <button
            class="nav-link active"
            id="home-tab"
            data-bs-toggle="tab"
            data-bs-target="#home"
            type="button"
            role="tab"
            aria-controls="home"
            aria-selected="true"
          >
            Home
          </button>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
          <button
            class="nav-link"
            id="profile-tab"
            data-bs-toggle="tab"
            data-bs-target="#profile"
            type="button"
            role="tab"
            aria-controls="profile"
            aria-selected="false"
          >
            Profile
          </button>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
          <button
            class="nav-link"
            id="contact-tab"
            data-bs-toggle="tab"
            data-bs-target="#contact"
            type="button"
            role="tab"
            aria-controls="contact"
            aria-selected="false"
          >
            Contact
          </button>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="tab-content d-flex flex-grow-1" id="myTabContent">
        <div
          class="tab-pane fade show active"
          id="home"
          role="tabpanel"
          aria-labelledby="home-tab"
        >
          <div class="form-group">
            <textarea class="form-control" id="MyTextarea" disabled>This is some placeholder content the Home tab's associated content. Clicking another tab will toggle the visibility of this one for the next. The tab JavaScript swaps classes to control the content visibility and styling. You can use it with tabs, pills, and any other .nav-powered navigation.This is some placeholder content the Home tab's associated content. Clicking another tab will toggle the visibility of this one for the next. The tab JavaScript swaps classes to control the content visibility and styling. You can use it with tabs, pills, and any other .nav-powered navigation.</textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div
          class="tab-pane fade"
          id="profile"
          role="tabpanel"
          aria-labelledby="profile-tab"
        >
          Profile Content
        </div>
        <div
          class="tab-pane fade"
          id="contact"
          role="tabpanel"
          aria-labelledby="contact-tab"
        >
          Contact Content
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer">
      Footer
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `flex-basis: 100%;` to your `#myTabContent`. Next, just simply add `h-100` or `(height: 100%;)` as a class on your `textarea` element.

```css
.card{
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
}

.tab-content{
  display: flex;
}

.tab-pane{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.form-group{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#myTabContent {
  flex-basis: 100%;
}

#MyTextarea{
  resize: none;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.slim.js" integrity="sha256-HwWONEZrpuoh951cQD1ov2HUK5zA5DwJ1DNUXaM6FsY=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
      Header
    </div>
    <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
        <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
          <button
            class="nav-link active"
            id="home-tab"
            data-bs-toggle="tab"
            data-bs-target="#home"
            type="button"
            role="tab"
            aria-controls="home"
            aria-selected="true"
          >
            Home
          </button>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
          <button
            class="nav-link"
            id="profile-tab"
            data-bs-toggle="tab"
            data-bs-target="#profile"
            type="button"
            role="tab"
            aria-controls="profile"
            aria-selected="false"
          >
            Profile
          </button>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
          <button
            class="nav-link"
            id="contact-tab"
            data-bs-toggle="tab"
            data-bs-target="#contact"
            type="button"
            role="tab"
            aria-controls="contact"
            aria-selected="false"
          >
            Contact
          </button>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="tab-content d-flex align-self-stretch" id="myTabContent">
        <div
          class="tab-pane fade show active"
          id="home"
          role="tabpanel"
          aria-labelledby="home-tab"
        >
          <div class="form-group">
            <textarea class="form-control h-100" id="MyTextarea" disabled>This is some placeholder content the Home tab's associated content. Clicking another tab will toggle the visibility of this one for the next. The tab JavaScript swaps classes to control the content visibility and styling. You can use it with tabs, pills, and any other .nav-powered navigation.This is some placeholder content the Home tab's associated content. Clicking another tab will toggle the visibility of this one for the next. The tab JavaScript swaps classes to control the content visibility and styling. You can use it with tabs, pills, and any other .nav-powered navigation.</textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div
          class="tab-pane fade"
          id="profile"
          role="tabpanel"
          aria-labelledby="profile-tab"
        >
          Profile Content
        </div>
        <div
          class="tab-pane fade"
          id="contact"
          role="tabpanel"
          aria-labelledby="contact-tab"
        >
          Contact Content
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer">
      Footer
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```